# Proxy settings at/prior to cloud-init runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-linux, cloud-init

Instances launched into our VPC in EC2 require `HTTP_PROXY` and partners to be set to access anything located outside the VPC.

Now I've run into a problem (using data pipeline) where I have no control over the user data passed in for cloud-config. Given the proxies are not set, I can see wget hanging (trying to connect) during the cloud-init user scripts.

Having set environment variables in `/etc/environment` it seems this is not read at runlevel 3 (this uses a positively ancient `Amazon Linux 2013.03`, and `ps axf` suggests it's called from runlevel 3, but I have to admit I'm not familiar with the various init daemons and their interaction with cloud-init):

```
 1354 ?        S      0:00  \_ /bin/bash /etc/rc3.d/S99cloud-init-user-scripts start
 1355 ?        S      0:00      \_ /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/cloud-init-run-module once-per-instance user-scripts execute run-parts /var/lib/cloud/data/scripts
 1356 ?        S      0:00          \_ /bin/bash /usr/bin/run-parts /var/lib/cloud/data/scripts
 1360 ?        S      0:00              \_ /bin/bash /var/lib/cloud/data/scripts/part-000
 1362 ?        S      0:00                  \_ wget -O remote-runner-install -N http://datapipeline-ap-southeast-2.s3.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2/bootstrap-actions/latest/TaskRu...
                                                \
                                                 \ This works in a login shell as I've set 
                                                   the variables in /etc/environment
```

Setting these variables here does not seem to work:

- /etc/environment
- /etc/sysconfig/cloudinit

How can I set the proxy used during cloud-init *runtime*?

Comment: As @ffledgling has noted, there does not seem to be a good solution at the moment. For anyone interested, I "solved" this problem by creating a copy of the datapipeline AMI with hardcoded proxies and configuring datapipeline to launch my hacked copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there's no good way to add a proxy to cloud init at run time. There's an open bug about it [on launchpad/cloud-init](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1089405).

There are work arounds mentioned in the comments, but they are all inherently application specific (for example for `yum` or `apt`), setting the proxy variables in their configs.

Comment: Given no one else has chimed in, and there does not seem to be a good solution to this, I will accept this as an answer. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

user-data example for cloud-init while creating ubuntu instance in openstack:

```yaml
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00-proxy
    permissions: 0640
    owner: root
    content: |
      Acquire::http { Proxy "http://example.com:8080"; };
      Acquire::https { Proxy "http://example.com:8080"; };
      Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth "23";
      Acquire::Languages "none";
   
package_upgrade: true

packages:
  - wget
  - sysstat
  - screen
```